# PDFBox renderImageWithDPI hangs sometimes

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am having trouble with PDFBox. I am using it to convert a PDF with a bunch of postage stamps to a BufferedImage which then gets cut into pieces (each individual stamp) and saved. This works fine on my main computer. However if I run it on an old crappy laptop (i5-4210U with 8gb ram) (Which I use as my server because of the low power usage and price) It will sometimes stop without any message or exception on the following line

```
BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageIndex, 400);
```

Most of the time it works on the second try, and it only happens on the first page. Once the first page worked it will render all following pages (tried up to about 40) without any issue.

I am using PDFBox 2.0.24 (tried 2.0.8 as well).
What could be the reason for that behaviour?

I can not share the any of the PDFs because it contains personal data but since it works on my main PC I think it does not have anything to do with the files.

Comment: Maybe you are leaking memory on your code, Try to check whether there are any resources not being closed which could be consuming memory which could be the main cause of your problem. It is unlikely though that your program would stop out of the blue without no exception, so look at your program logs or it may be a java log at the machine level. Could be that the java process itself stopped and you would see this only on the OS server level.

Comment: Make sure that server has the latest update of the jdk you're using. For example, the latest jdk8 is 1.8.0_302.

Comment: I don't think there are any memory leaks. The programm sometimes runs for months without being restarted and not using any more memory than it does at the beginning. The Java version could have been the problem. There was some ancient version still installed somehow which I did not notice. I deleted that one and now it seems to work. I have tried about 20 files. Maybe I was just lucky (or unlucky in this case) and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled over this question again after forgetting about it.
Updating the java jdk on the server to the newest version actually resolved the problem and it has not happened since then.